# A specific role only reaction

Tags: discord, discord.py

I'm trying to get it so a specific role can react to the message to be able to ban the user, I have made the ability to be able to react to the message, and the author of the command can ban the user, but I want to make it so another role can do it as well
Here is what I have currently

```
      def check(rctn, user):
        return user.id == ctx.author.id and str(rctn) == '<:tick:837398197931868190>'
      reaction, user = await bot.wait_for('reaction_add', check=check)
```

Comment: What is this a about? A `command` or `event`?

Comment: A command, basically someone requests to ban someone and a higher up reacts to ban.

Comment: Is `@commands.has_role()` helping you?

Comment: I don't know where to put it though, I know I have to put that in there.

Comment: @bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@commands.has_permissions`

For example you could make it:

```
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)

# rest of your code
```

This way only roles with the permissions to `ban_members` can use the command